# Is a Google CDN advantageous over another for same file

Tags: jquery, cdn

I am wondering about advantages to using a Google CDN over another CDN.  For example, I saw this [posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014203/best-way-to-use-googles-hosted-jquery-but-fall-back-to-my-hosted-library-on-go) on SO with one of the answers giving the example to use Google's CDN for jquery.

What are the advantages to using

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

as opposed  to referencing from jquery's site?

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
```

Are there any or no it comes down to just a preference?

Comment: You could have a regional advantage depending on the CDN and usually would want to use the biggest CDN as that would make it most likely that a user already has the file cached.

Comment: So does it matter where the files was sourced from for caching and not the file itself?  For example if a user visited a site previously that had google cdn for jquery and then visited my site that had a code.jquery.com cdn it would have to redownload?

Comment: It would depend on the browser but most likely yes.

Answer (score 0):

CDNs will have different:

- capacity - determines how quickly your users download it
- locations around the world - similar impact to capacity depending on location
- user utilisation - increases the chances they have already downloaded the library and cached it from another website
- libraries served - it is easier to use a single CDN that has most libraries you'll use

The first 3 are impossible to work out or require a lot of research. The last 1 Google has an advantage over the jQuery CDN, assuming you are using other libraries.

Most of the CDNs are so good now that you and your user won't notice a difference. Pick the one that is easiest for you.